# Printing out Arrays?

Tags: java

When I print out the coding for

```
    //display the board
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            char [][] gameboardTwo = {{'*', '*', 'S', 'T', 'A','R', '*', 'W', 'A', 'R', 'S', '*', '*', '*'}, {'*', '*', 'E','P', 'I', 'S', 'O', 'D', 'E', '*', '*', 'I', 'V', '*'}, {'*', '*', '*','*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'}, {'*', '*', '*','*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'}};
            System.out.print(gameboardTwo);
        }

}
```

all I get in return is this:

```
[[C@75b84c92
Process completed.
```

Comment: Not a huge Java expert but it looks like what is printing is the array reference and not the contents. See this other question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array

Answer (score 10):

A 2-D array can be printed using :

```
System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(gameboardTwo));
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are represented as `String`s similarly to what the `Object.toString` method prints out, that is, with a type and a hash code.

To print your array, you must use the static utility methods of the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class.

For instance:  `Arrays.toString(yourArray)`.

In your case, `Arrays.deepToString(yourArray)` since it has multiple dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `System.out.println()` Method in Java, it will print out the given Object by using its `toString()`Method.

In general this method just prints out a Text which uniquely identifies the Object. This standard implementation is where the

```
[[C@75b84c92
```

comes from in your example.

If you want to print out the entire content of your array you have two Options:

Either use the `Arrays.toString()` or `Arrays.deepToString()` methods.
Or you iterate over the contents of the array and print out the data manually.

See
[What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

something to remember about arrays is that they're a collection of items.

When you want to print out a collection of items, generally it makes sense to get each item in the array and print it out separate. So if you have a collection of strings, you iterate through each item in the array and print out the string.

if you have a collection of ints, objects, or other datatype, you can use the `.toString()` method of that datatype so that it can be turned into a string to print out. I think Java implicitly does that for certain data types when you try to print them out.

ex.

```
String[] myArray = {"a", "b", "c"};

void printArray() {
 for (String s : myArray) {
  System.out.print(s);
 }
 //or a traditional for loop, I forget how to get the length of 
 //an array in Java
 for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  System.out.print(myArray[i]);
 }
 //in your case, multidimensional array, this should work
 //haven't tested it though
 String[][] myArray = {{"a","b"},{"c","d"}};
 for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
   System.out.print(myArray[i][j]);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting indivisual elements of the array follow below code :-

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         char [][] gameboardTwo = {
                                      {'*', '*', 'S', 'T', 'A','R', '*', 'W', 'A', 'R', 'S', '*', '*', '*'}, 
                                      {'*', '*', 'E','P', 'I', 'S', 'O', 'D', 'E', '*', '*', 'I', 'V', '*'}, 
                                      {'*', '*', '*','*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'}, 
                                      {'*', '*', '*','*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'}
                                  };
         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(gameboardTwo));
         System.out.println("////////////////////////////");
         System.out.println(gameboardTwo[0].length);
         System.out.println("////////////////////////////");
         for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
             for(int j=0; j<14; j++){
                 System.out.println(gameboardTwo[i][j]);
             }
             System.out.println("**** row ends ****");
         }

     }
```